Codes from orthogonal stabilizer states
This article discusses the equivalence between code word stabilized (CWS) and union stabilizer codes. This family with two names is also equivalent to the graph codes discussed in Nonadditive Quantum Error-Correcting Code
and Graphical Quantum Error-Correcting Codes
Whatever you want to call this family, it includes a lot of well known codes like those found in the papers above as well as in the similarly titled A Nonadditive Quantum Code and Simple Family of Nonadditive Codes. Explicit realizations of all of these as CWS codes are given well in Codeword Stabilized Quantum Codes.
It is clear by construction that every codespace of every CWS has an orthonormal basis consisting of stabilizer states. But is the converse also true?
In other words my question is: suppose we have a codespace that can be spanned by orthogonal stabilizer states, then must the code be a CWS code?
For example it is noted in the original Rains paper on the $ ((5,6,2)) $ code that the 6 basis vectors for the codespace are all $ [[5,0,3]] $ stabilizer states. Is that knowledge enough to guarantee that the code is CWS?
